# Compile error in VS.NET 2008 (VB.NET) that I can't get rid of!

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, compiler-construction, windows-vista

I can't shake this error when compiling my Visual Studio.NET 2008 solution.  The project that's generating the error is a VB.NET Web Application in a 12 project solution (mixed types and languages).

I've tried all the tricks I can find on google, and the obvious of removing the directoy and folder manually.

I'm running Vista Business 32 with VS.NET 2008 SP1.  This just started happening out of the blue today and I've rebooted a bunch and even re-applied SP1 for VS.NET.

Any ideas or has anybody seen this?

vbc : **error BC31019**: **Unable to write to output file** 'G:\Projects\TCA.NET\TcaNet\WebUI\obj\Debug\TcaNet.WebUI.pdb': **Unspecified error**

**Update:**

After thinking about this and not finding any solutions from answers or via the Internet, I went ahead and moved my entire solution to my C:\ drive vs. my G:\ drive (both are local).  Doing this fixed my compile problem for some reason.

Comment: So, I assume that neither the drive is full nor there is a file with "readonly" applied to it? The directory is existing too? Hm...

Comment: The file is not read only.  Also, the folder does exist.  If you remove the folder completely, it always recreates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this and not finding any solutions from answers or via the Internet, I went ahead and moved my entire solution to my C:\ drive vs. my G:\ drive (both are local). Doing this fixed my compile problem for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error a few weeks ago when I was compiling on my server from my laptop. Turns out that if G: is a network drive, this could fail. Microsoft have said that fixing this is not a priority, and that there's much better ways of doing things (such as source control). For a one-man project though, it's a pain.

Comment: My G:\ drive is a local disk.

Answer (score 2):

Restart IIS on local.

If that's not the issue then, install [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and try to delete that pdb file when you get the error, Unlocker will tell you which process is holding an open handle to that file.

Comment: I can delete the file just fine every time through Explorer.  Unlocker doesn't show any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a list of thing to try to fix your problem :

[Zen-turkey Fix list](http://zen-turkey.com/blog/default.aspx?id=34&t=Visual-Studio-2005-VBC-Error-BC31019-Un)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

maybe it is a dependency problem. check the build order of all the projects..

sysinternals tools should be of help here. using process explorer, are you able to find out if any process is locking this file? another useful tool is process monitor. after applying a filter for the pdb file, capture a trace of all file access activity..

Comment: It has been working fine for months, not sure why it would just start today when I haven't added any new DLLs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably bug in VB.NET compiler. The error message is incorrect, the real problem is missing file referenced from the project file. For example .vb file.
In my case, I found the missing file and added it, then devenv compiled fine again.

Someone reported that to MS [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/218639/wrong-error-description#details)

Comment: By visually looking for a missing .vb source file in the project and updating the project to not look for the file, this error went away for me.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is very old thread, but I got this error today and the following link solved it. Hope it help someone reading this.

[VB.NET .pdb fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627523/unable-to-create-pdb-file)

Answer (score 0):

I had this in Visual Studio 2005 except it was Error 1. I restarted my machine and it fixed the problem.