# unable to write output file ... pdb visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

From other answers to this same question, it seems that this error is secondary to the real problem which is a missing source file. I am not using any source control. I have looked through my entire project and don't see any files with a warning icon, indicating it's missing. If there IS a file missing, what is it missing from?

How can I find the "missing" file? Isn't there any way of resetting this? My whole project is stuck on this.

Comment: 1) You don't need the .pdb - you can simply delete and and rebuild your project.  2) We do need the exact error message to help you.  3) SUGGESTION: [Select] your project, click [Clean], then [Build]

Comment: Error 4 Unable to write to output file 'C:\projects\azure\ReadnQuiz\ReadnQuiz\obj\Debug\ReadnQuiz.pdb': Unspecified error. Posting code isn't going to help with this. Cleaning does nothing, rebuilding (which usually helps in casese like this) doesn't help. Rebooting doesn't help.

Comment: BTW, I have done a ton of research on this all morning, which I always do before posting. As I stated in the question, other answers given elsewhere are either vague or I am missing something, I am attempting to get more information. This seems to be a quasi bug in VS, not telling you a.) there is a missing file, and b.)what the name of the file is. If anyone knows how to ascertain the name of the missing file, that would really help.

Comment: Is the file present in the debug folder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create PDB file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627523/unable-to-create-pdb-file)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had this too. Close VS and reopen. Don't compile. The errors list should tell you which file is missing.

Comment: Same error here and it was a file missing. I just searched for exclamation icon in front of any file in my solution and found one. Deleted that file and "build" started to work ! Thanks @Chip !

Comment: This solved it for me. Mine happen to be I ignore changes to a file in Github app, then it deletes the file too in my system!

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. My project was building in release mode but was not working in debug mode. I checked for all necesary files are included in my solution and I found that there is one file missing Settings.Designer.vb in My Project folder. I included  these file in project and it build file in debug mode also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all aspx files are available in your solutions, otherwise check WebSite.vbproj, make sure maybe there is a file that is missing from your code, either add this file to the solution, or remove it from WebSite.vbproj. I recommend for you to use Notepad++ to open and modify WebSite.vbproj

Regards,
Luai

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is the existence of corrupted compiled dlls for the actual project (i.e. `bin/<project>.dll`) In my case, I just deleted the .dll and the .pdb and recompiled and the error went away.

Answer (score -1):

Deleting removed files from the Solution Explorer, then rebuilding, solved it on my computer.

Comment: This already has accepted answer ! And what the second comment about? Are you intending to write for some other question ?